# Sort ascending the result with vba inside a loop

Tags: vba, sorting

Can anyone tells me how I can sort the result in ascending/descending order in the below code?
This is the main code from the total code.
probably it will be placed in the `.font.bold = true`

```
Public Sub FileLister(rootPath As String, exploreSubFolder As Boolean)

    Dim file As Scripting.file, folder As Scripting.folder, subfolder As Scripting.folder

    If fso Is Nothing Then
        Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    End If

    Set folder = fso.GetFolder(rootPath)

    If (folder.SubFolders.Count > 0) And exploreSubFolder Then
    
        For Each subfolder In folder.SubFolders
            
            nestLevel = nestLevel + 1
            ReDim Preserve navigated(nestLevel)
            
            If navigated(nestLevel) = 0 Then
                For Each file In folder.Files
                    anchorRange.Offset(printRow, nestLevel + 1).Value = file.Name
                    anchorRange.Offset(printRow, 0).Hyperlinks.Add Control.Range("A12").Offset(printRow, 0), file.path, , , "Go To"
                    printRow = printRow + 1
                Next file
            End If
            
            anchorRange.Offset(printRow, nestLevel + 1).Value = subfolder.Name
            anchorRange.Offset(printRow, nestLevel + 1).Font.Bold = True
            anchorRange.Offset(printRow, 0).Hyperlinks.Add Control.Range("A12").Offset(printRow, 0), subfolder.path, , , "Go To"
            printRow = printRow + 1
            navigated(nestLevel) = 1
            FileLister subfolder.path, exploreSubFolder
            nestLevel = nestLevel - 1
            
        Next subfolder
        
    Else
    
        nestLevel = nestLevel + 1
        For Each file In folder.Files
            'Record files in folder
            anchorRange.Offset(printRow, nestLevel + 1).Value = file.Name
            anchorRange.Offset(printRow, 0).Hyperlinks.Add Control.Range("A12").Offset(printRow, 0), file.path, , , "Go To"
            printRow = printRow + 1
        Next file
        For Each subfolder In folder.SubFolders
            anchorRange.Offset(printRow, nestLevel + 1).Value = subfolder.Name
            anchorRange.Offset(printRow, nestLevel + 1).Font.Bold = True
            anchorRange.Offset(printRow, 0).Hyperlinks.Add Control.Range("A12").Offset(printRow, 0), subfolder.path, , , "Go To"
            printRow = printRow + 1
        Next subfolder
        nestLevel = nestLevel - 1
        
        'If exploreSubFolder Then
         '   navigated(nestLevel) = 0
        'End If
        
                
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Sort by what information?

Comment: the result from the loop

Comment: When the loop is done, sort the range.  You can use the macro recorder to get the code for that.